# How can I receive a notification for new reviews for an add-on in the Google Sheets add-on store?

Tags: google-sheets, notifications, google-sheets-addons

I would like to receive a notification (preferably email) for every new review left on the add-on store page for a specific add-on.

Example for such a page: [Sheetgo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sheetgo/baljgggfhdleglaneclmjhhmflaombln)

Review section:

[image]